# Ionic serve is not able to display local assets

Tags: angular, windows, ionic-framework, onedrive

I will post this and answer my own question, maybe it can help someone.

Today I spent an unholy amount of hours trying to understand why the command ionic serve didn't load any of my local assets, no images, no translations...

It worked on other computers, so it had to be a problem with my computer.

I use a Windows 11, with OneDrive connected.

Read the answer to see how to fix it if maybe you are in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, Android Studio gave me the key.

It turns out OneDrive did a copy of my repository on the cloud, without me knowing, and ionic serve was somehow using that wrong path instead of the local one.

So all I had to do was turn of OneDrive (and I fully disabled it cause it's really annoying), remove the repo from my computer and pull it again. And everything worked fine!